# Warning when using color control in React JS

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using React JS with Babel and Webpack. Everything has worked fine with my other scripts even ones that use the color module, however, one of my scripts is giving me the following error:

> The specified value "" does not conform to the required format.  The
>   format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal
>   numbers.

My code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

class EditDetails extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bg: "#ffffff"
        };
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const id = target.id;

            this.setState({
                [id]: value
            });
    }




  render() {
      return (
            <div>
                 <form>
                    <div>Background Colour:<input id="bg" type="color" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value="#dddddd" /></div>
                  </form>
            </div>
      )
  }
}

export default EditDetails;
```

If I remove the `value="#dddddd"` from my input tag it actually gives the same error message twice.

Upon further investigation, the error reference points me to the following section in ReactDOMInput.js:

```
switch (props.type) {
  case 'submit':
  case 'reset':
    break;
  case 'color':
  case 'date':
  case 'datetime':
  case 'datetime-local':
  case 'month':
  case 'time':
  case 'week':
    // This fixes the no-show issue on iOS Safari and Android Chrome:
    // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7233
    node.value = '';
    node.value = node.defaultValue;
    break;
  default:
    node.value = node.value;
    break;
}
```

Specifically it is referring to the first `node.value` line (or the first two `node.value` lines when I remove the `value` attribute).

Why is this error being generated when I have the colour code in the correct hexadecimal format?

Note: The correct colour does indeed appear correctly set in the color control.

Comment: ```this.setState( { [id]: `#${value}` } );``` or write the color with the #.

Comment: @RafaelBerro This does not seem to be correct as the color control supplies the # symbol. Also, the error is generated upon initial render, not on subsequent changes to the value.

Comment: Where are you applying the bg state?

Comment: It is not currently being applied in my example. I removed a lot of clutter to focus just on the problem. The entire code that you see here is my entire class that still gives the error.

Comment: I know why, the component are calling the handleChange function when it renders because you did the binding the wrong way, this way, the parameter 'event' are null and it has no target property.

Comment: @RafaelBerro please see my comment under your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am technically on the same error, but i don't think it has nothing to do with onChange. Simply because my onChange function is different from the one in the question and I already had a different working version of my code that was working with onChange. 
The one in the question:

```
handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const id = target.id;

            this.setState({
                [id]: value
            });
    }
```

Versus Mine:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };
```

And we BOTH get the same error, regardless of the difference in the structure of our onChange functions.

In case it might help anyone else though- this is a version that works:

```
class CheckBoxes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { color: "" };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ color: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    // const [initial, setInitial] = useState("#5e72e4");
    // const [color, setColor] = useState({});

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="color"
          value={this.state.color}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            marginBottom: 20,
            backgroundColor: this.state.color
          }}
        ></div>
        <br />
        {/* <InputColor initialHexColor={initial} onChange={setColor} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CheckBoxes;
```

Basically: backgroundColor of div will change when the value of the input changes.

Comment: However, the part where you state that it is not related to `onChange` could actually be considered an answer. Could you elaborate and remove the rest?

Comment: No, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiselleMartinez006/BryanUniversity_WebDev/master/Week5/SharedScreenshot.jpg

Comment: You could flag your own post and explain to the moderator that you want to but cannot delete and why you want to. But I recommend turning it into an answer instead. Edit to remove the first line. Add any detail you can think of, e.g. what makes you think that it is not related. Then you should be fine (and you get to keep the reputation you got for this).

Comment: I suppose I can try to elaborate on it. Although mine is slightly different because it is caused as i try to apply the color value as a style property of something else..

Comment: Do you notice the orange banner at the top of your browser, which asks your to complete signing up for your account? Maybe that is what keeps you from deleting (though I still think you should not...).

Comment: You were right, i see it now. But i'll take your advice and elaborate on it- Thank You!

Comment: Is that any better? Or should i show all of the code? Since my case is kinda different I didn't want to make the answer revolve around showing all my code that has a different nature than hers which seems only one component. To show mine I would have to show all the input component, and its parent and the grandparent to include all meaningful pieces to the problem.

Comment: Looks like helpful contribution without being to long. I am not actually knowledgable on the technology. But it now looks seriously like an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205367/discussion-between-gisellemtnezs-and-yunnosch).

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your function in the class constructor, this way.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class EditDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { bg: '#ffffff' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { target } = event;
    const { id, value } = target;

    this.setState(
      { [id]: value }
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <input id='bg' type='color' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.bg} />
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have made the change as you suggested but it made no difference. I think your approach is just an alternative to my approach.  Also, why are you using getInitialState with an ES6 class, shouldn't the state be defined in the constructor as I had it?

Comment: Also, it may be worth noting that even if I remove the onChange attribute completely that I still get the same error, which leads me to believe it has nothing to do with the onChange function.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is with this piece of code? Can you log the event parameter of the handleChange event and see what happens? Also, try to remove the input and see if it stills happening.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Even if I remove the handleChange function and call, I still get the same error. When the input is removed no error shows up. If I add a second input the error is repeated a second time. I have logged the event parameter, the handleChange function is not invoked until an input changes. The handleChange function does not trigger an error. The error only shows up when the class first renders. I even tried adding a state change in the handleChange function and still no error is generated. The error only happens on initial class render, not when the handleChange function is called.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I do remove the handleChange call in my input statement, I get a warning that says: "Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler...." This is then followed by the color error.