# Color Input in React: The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, types, colors

Full Warning: 
`react-dom.development.js:2592 The specified value "" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers.`

The code IS WORKING FINE. It is doing what it is supposed to do, which is: each input changes the background color of the squares that appear/get updated once the button is pressed.

The only instance when the code was working and the warning was not appearing- was during development as i was messing with the color input and I was trying to change the background of a mockdiv that was part of the same component as the input. The second i lifted state it started behaving like this.

But the BEST PART IS: When I tell It to Console.log the this.state.color.hex (which is the value that changes the background color) It console.logs "#00ff40" "#ff0000" "#0000ff" AND "#ffff00" - Which is why I have no idea how to get rid of this warning.

I don't think this error is caused by the changeHandler function. I have had MANY different versions of this function and it has had little impact on this warning. As well, the other question to this warning ([Warning when using color control in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195849/warning-when-using-color-control-in-react-js/59595451#59595451) ) has another completely different version of a changeHandler function and still has the same error. AND I originally had a one single changeHandler function for all instances of the value color prop, and the error was still there. BUT if it is- I would love to know how to change it if it means getting rid of this warning.

The structure summary is:

Checkbox => ButtonPerSquare =>HOME

Squares => SquaresWrapper   =>HOME

Then Home merges the two and renders the squares on the click of the button, which is also on Home.

Checkbox.js: //i know is not a befitting name, but it was already called like that on my template for each new project.

```
import React from "react";
class CheckBoxes extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type={this.props.type}
          className={this.props.class}
          value={
            this.props.class === "input1"
              ? this.props.color1
              : this.props.class === "input2"
              ? this.props.color2
              : this.props.class === "input3"
              ? this.props.color3
              : this.props.class === "input4"
              ? this.props.color4
              : console.log("blue")
          }
          onChange={
            this.props.class === "input1"
              ? event => this.props.handleChange1(event)
              : this.props.class === "input2"
              ? event => this.props.handleChange2(event)
              : this.props.class === "input3"
              ? event => this.props.handleChange3(event)
              : this.props.class === "input4"
              ? event => this.props.handleChange4(event)
              : console.log("blue")
          }
        />
        <span>{this.props.sp1}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CheckBoxes;
```

ButtonPerSquare.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkboxes from "./Checkboxes";
// import "./../App.css";
const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
// const colors = ["#ffffff", "#F7E3B3", "#71EB92", "#000fff"];
const classes = ["input1", "input2", "input3", "input4"];
class HeaderButtons extends Component {
  render() {
    //sp is for the span element in the Checkboxes function.
    return (
      <header className={this.props.headerClass}>
        {numbers.map((nums, col) => {
          //   const keys = numbers[nums];
          //   console.log(keys);
          return (
            <Checkboxes
              color1={this.props.color1}
              color2={this.props.color2}
              color3={this.props.color3}
              color4={this.props.color4}
              // color2={this.props.color2}
              // color3={this.props.color3}
              // color4={this.props.color4}
              handleChange1={event => this.props.handleChange1(event)}
              handleChange2={event => this.props.handleChange2(event)}
              handleChange3={event => this.props.handleChange3(event)}
              handleChange4={event => this.props.handleChange4(event)}
              //this.props.handleChange}
              background={this.props.background}
              // className="ColorInput"
              // color={this.props.color}
              sp1={nums}
              key={nums}
              type="color"
              // defaultValue={colors[col]}
              class={classes[col]}
              //   value="red"
            />
          );
        })}
        {/* one parethesis for return.. one curly for the funct... another parenthesis for map... and the blue curly THEN closing header */}
      </header>
    );
  }
}
export default HeaderButtons;
```

Square.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Squares extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id={this.props.id}
        className="Square"
        style={{
          background:
            this.props.id === "square1"
              ? this.props.background1
              : this.props.id === "square2"
              ? this.props.background2
              : this.props.id === "square3"
              ? this.props.background3
              : this.props.id === "square4"
              ? this.props.background4
              : console.log("blue")
        }}
      >
        Blue
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Squares;
```

SquaresWrapper.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Squares from "./Squares";
// import "./../App.css";
const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
// const backgrounds = ["#ffffff", "#F7E3B3", "#71EB92", "#000fff"];
const classes = ["square1", "square2", "square3", "square4"];
class SquaresWrapper extends Component {
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  //   this.state = {};
  // }

  render() {
    //sp is for the span element in the Checkboxes function.
    return (
      <section className={this.props.sectionClass}>
        {numbers.map((nums, col) => {
          //   const keys = numbers[nums];
          //   console.log(keys);
          return (
            <Squares
              id={classes[col]}
              key={nums}
              background1={this.props.background1}
              background2={this.props.background2}
              background3={this.props.background3}
              background4={this.props.background4}
              //   value="red"
            />
          );
        })}
        {/* one parethesis for return.. one curly for the funct... another parenthesis for map... and the blue curly THEN closing header */}
      </section>
    );
  }
}
export default SquaresWrapper;
```

Home:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HeaderButtons from "./ButtonPerSquare";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// import Paragraph from "./Paragraph";
import SquaresWrapper from "./squaresWrapper";
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color1: { hex: "" },
      color2: { hex: "" },
      color3: { hex: "" },
      color4: { hex: "" }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="creatorDiv">
        <HeaderButtons
          color1={this.state.color1.hex}
          color2={this.state.color2.hex}
          color3={this.state.color3.hex}
          color4={this.state.color4.hex}
          handleChange1={event =>
            this.setState({
              color1: { hex: event.target.value }
            })
          }
          handleChange2={event =>
            this.setState({
              color2: { hex: event.target.value }
            })
          }
          handleChange3={event =>
            this.setState({
              color3: { hex: event.target.value }
            })
          }
          handleChange4={event =>
            this.setState({
              color4: { hex: event.target.value }
            })
          }
          headerClass="HeaderDiv"
        />
        <button
          onMouseDown={() =>
            ReactDOM.render(
              <SquaresWrapper
                sectionClass="squaresWrapper"
                background1={this.state.color1.hex}
                // {this.state.color1}
                background2={this.state.color2.hex}
                // {this.state.color2}
                background3={this.state.color3.hex}
                // {this.state.color3}
                background4={this.state.color4.hex}
                // {this.state.color4}
              />,
              document.getElementById("blue")
            )
          }
        >
          Create Color
        </button>
        <div id="blue"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Is there any sort of stack trace that tells you where the error is manifesting from?

Comment: @DrewReese Stack Trace?

Comment: Yes, it usually accompanies errors and warnings in the console. There may be something you have to expand that gives you more details about the origins of the error/warning. Sometimes you can literally click the error and it'll open the source up in the browser where the error occurred. Just dumping a bunch of files and saying there's an error somewhere isn't likely to get you help quickly. My hunch is you have some `undefined` or malformed state or prop value(s) that is quickly populated and thus your app runs fine, but with occasional warnings.

Comment: Like this in `Home`, `this.state = {
      color1: { hex: "" },
      color2: { hex: "" },
      color3: { hex: "" },
      color4: { hex: "" }
    };` none of these are properly formatted hexadecimal color values.

Comment: The warning doesn't show up at the beginning when the states are like that though. It shows up when I press the button that send the color[].hex to the background prop of the squares. Like when the whole thing renders, it looks fine, but when I press the button there it pops.

Comment: When I touch the only link on the warning it takes me all the way to code inside the react app, this is probably somewhere in the node modules folder (?) is not any code I wrote. Should i take a screenshot of it?

Comment: Or better yet, should i add the link to the github url where i save the whole thing?

Comment: Screenshots are not recommended, but copy/paste is. If you can, please include/update as much information of the error/warning as possible in the question. Even better if you can replicate your issue in an online codesandbox where someone can run it and see it while it is working.

Comment: I tried to create it in the sandbox, but there it doesn't show up the warning.  Is a yellow colored warning- doesn't seem to have any direct effect with the actual procedure of the app. It also shows up on another part of the app where I added a new button and passed the value there are "blue" which works fine too. Maybe is cause I create the react app with npx create-react-app.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-ellis-tgy3t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Took me a second to figure out how to use your UI, but after changing and adding a few colors I don't see any warnings in the console at all. I'm on Chrome 79, what browser are you using? It may just be a browser specific warning that can be ignored.

Comment: ui? I know it stands for UserInterface but what does that mean in this case? There wasn't any warnings showing at all on the sandbox either. I noticed at some point after I kept adding buttons it somehow disappeared. So I was thinking about it. And i think you were right to point out the { color1: { hex: "" }, color2: { hex: "" }. The most major difference I made after I kept adding buttons was that { color1: { hex: "" }, color2: { hex: "" } turned to => { color1: { hex: "white" }, color2: { hex: "white" } as the default value to go there.

Comment: I'll test that out right now..

Comment: Hmm, nope. I changed it back to hex: "" as default state and it is not showing the error anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a simple solution for this warning "This warning does not conform to the required format.  The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers."

use default value in input[type=color]

```
<input type="color" name="xyz" value="#ffffff" id="xyz" >
```

#ffffff is default value or format.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer, but the warning is coming from Blink which is Chrome's DOM implementation.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/011c27ced479c76cffd5093ce107082e4da657f3/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/forms/color_input_type.cc#190

If you create an `<input type=color>` and then set the `.value` to an unsupported value, it will issue that warning.  There's no way to disable this warning, you can only avoid it by not setting the `.value` to an invalid value.

MDN explains this a bit too:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#Value

> Setting the value to anything that isn't a valid, fully-opaque, RGB color in hexadecimal notation will result in the value being set to #000000.

I can't speak for React, but maybe it does this sort of thing incidentally.

HTH.